# Ansible version compare

Tags: ansible

Trying to compare the installed package version and upgrade to latest version in Ansible, Blocked at when package is not installed in server.

```
- debug:
    msg: "Installed version is null or lower than {{ gcc_new_version.stdout }}"
  when: 'gcc_version.stdout == "" || gcc_version.stdout is version(gcc_new_version.stdout, '<')
```

Error:

fatal:  FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'gcc_version.stdout == "" || gcc_version.stdout is version(gcc_new_version.stdout, '<')' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token 'name', got '|'. String: {% if gcc_version.stdout == "" || gcc_version.stdout is version(gcc_new_version.stdout, '<') %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in 'ansible/roles/linux/tasks/gcc.yml': line 24, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug:\n  ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the syntax in `when` condition. Conditions are in Jinja context, so use of single quotes `'` around conditions is not required. Also the `or` keyword can be used instead of `||`.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "Installed version is null or lower than {{ gcc_new_version.stdout }}"
  when: (gcc_version.stdout == "") or (gcc_version.stdout is version_compare(gcc_new_version.stdout, '<'))
```